# sklearn cross_val_score always returning same non zero values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I tried using a logistic regression model to predict some data and the first time I use cross_val_score it seems fine.  But when I tried to drop some of the less important features and rerun cross_val_score on the limited data it gives the same accuracy scores.  I even replaced my data with all 0s and it still gives the same result.

first I do

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = data_only.drop('status_label', axis=1)
y = data_only['status_label']
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

model = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
cv_scores = cross_val_score(model, X_scaled, y, cv=5)
print("CV Scores",  cv_scores)
```

then I filter the columns and try to rerun the cross validation with top_feature_df which has some of the columns removed

```
X_filtered = top_feature_df
X_scaled_filtered = scaler.fit_transform(X_filtered)
model_filtered = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
cv_scores_filtered = cross_val_score(model_filtered, X_scaled_filtered, y, cv=5)
print("CV Scores\t\t",  cv_scores)
print("CV Scores Filtered\t",  cv_scores_filtered)
```

the last 2 print statements give the same values

I even set

```
top_feature_df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(y), 1)))
```

to make a dataframe with only 0s and it still returns the same accuracy scores.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide a full minimal reproducible example that we can run on our machines, so that we get the same results and can help you?